# Como achar brechas de série temporal?

Tags: r, join, series-temporais

Eu tenho várias séries temporais com brechas. Ou seja, dia tem observação, passa uns dias sem, ai volta observar e assim segue com furos. O problema é que juntaram essas séries no arquivo. Se tiver faltando um mês de dados diários, a empresa que preencheu não deixou os dias sem observação com NA ou -9.9e10. A empresa juntou. Ou seja, numa planilha de excel é como se na linha seguinte a linha com a observação para 02/03/1995 tivesse a observação de 10/03/1995. Ou seja, um furo de 8 dias.

Eu então gerei uma sequencia de datas partindo de um ano base (1900) até 2018 e queria achar as brechas das séries e unir ela a essa sequencia de datas num data.frame.

Eu estou usando a função `full_join()` do `dplyr`, mas ta saindo todo errado.

Eu queria que essa união fosse em função da sequencia de datas que criei, nem mais nem menos. De forma a poder ter um data frame regular no final.

Algum método pra fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que o join que resolve o teu problema é o `left_join`. Veja abaixo:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# criacao dos dias de referencia

dias <- seq.Date(from = dmy("01-01-2001"), 
                 to = dmy("10-01-2001"), 
                 by = "1 day")

# data frame de exemplo

dados <- data.frame(dias, observacoes = 1:10)

# retirando algunas dados dele

missing <- dados[-c(2, 3, 7), ]

missing
#>          dias observacoes
#> 1  2001-01-01           1
#> 4  2001-01-04           4
#> 5  2001-01-05           5
#> 6  2001-01-06           6
#> 8  2001-01-08           8
#> 9  2001-01-09           9
#> 10 2001-01-10          10

# completando o data frame

left_join(as.data.frame(dias), missing)
#> Joining, by = "dias"
#>          dias observacoes
#> 1  2001-01-01           1
#> 2  2001-01-02          NA
#> 3  2001-01-03          NA
#> 4  2001-01-04           4
#> 5  2001-01-05           5
#> 6  2001-01-06           6
#> 7  2001-01-07          NA
#> 8  2001-01-08           8
#> 9  2001-01-09           9
#> 10 2001-01-10          10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>